# Should cookie encryption key be unique?

Tags: security, encryption, cookies

Plese advice whether it is ok to have one encryption key stored somewhere which will be used to encrypt cookies for all users, and in this case the key probably will be rarely changed.
Or the key should be unique for each user or session ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 0: cookies probably shouldn't store *encrypted* data to begin with but only meaningless tokens…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reuse keys for ciphers. However, you must then make sure that your ciphertext is properly randomized by providing a nonce or IV according to the mode in which the cipher is used. There may also be bounds on how many times the key can be used, but generally those numbers are relatively high. Again, this depends on the cipher scheme being used.

This is a direct answer, I agree with [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679319/should-cookie-encryption-key-be-unique#comment109100690_61679319) that storing ciphertext in a cookie may not be what you ultimately need.